# R traceback writes too much to console

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a large data.frame as an input and returns an environment. Something is wrong with the function and it throws a mysterious error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent"
```

I call `traceback()` to investigate further, and part of the traceback prints all of the data, outputting over 200,000 lines and 15 MB of data to the terminal.

The data.frame I am using is already of class `tbl.df` from the `dplyr` package, which under normal circumstances suppresses printing of the entire data.frame.

To capture the output of traceback, I use the `sink` function to write to file.

Is there anyway to avoid traceback printing an excessive amount of output to the console?

Comment: Try putting a `browser()` call in front of the offending line and step through the code manually or set `options(error = recover)`.

Comment: Thanks, I know browser is an option. Is there any way to print a stack trace in R that includes one line of output per function call in the stack?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.